# Why does my cron job run every 1 minute although I set it every 1 hour?

Tags: cron

I set my cron job via `crontab -e`, with the following code:

```
* */1 * * * python /var/www/your_script >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I didn't add `.py` extension as it makes the cron job invalid.

However, after logging it by `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`, the script is executed every one minute, not every one hour.

```
Mar  1 07:40:01 my-instance CRON[4471]: (me) CMD (python /var/www/your_script >/dev/null 2>&1)
Mar  1 07:41:01 my-instance CRON[4474]: (me) CMD (python /var/www/your_script >/dev/null 2>&1)
Mar  1 07:42:01 my-instance CRON[4477]: (me) CMD (python /var/www/your_script >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

Why does my script start to be run every one minute, not every one hour? My environment is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: No, you set it to every minute of every hour. Pick a fixed minute for the first column.

Comment: Or you could use `0 * * * *` which means 0 minutes after every full hour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to set cronjob for every hour, you can do it any of following way:

You can run:

```
0 * * * * /path/to/script
```

which reads

> On minute 0, each hour, each day of month, each month, each day of the week.

or

```
@hourly /path/to/script
```

or

```
0 */1 * * * /path/to/script
```

An asterisk (`*`) can be used so that every instance (every hour, every weekday, every month, etc.) of a time period is used.

Reference:
[crontab](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab),
[CronHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

Comment: Thanks. So are `0 */1 * * *` and `0 * * * *` the same in this case?

Comment: Hmmmm I'm pretty confused now. So is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11562834/2360798) wrong? The question is how to run the script every 6 hours and the answer is `0 */6 * * *`.

Comment: Also, then how about `0 1 * * *`? I though it is "run at every 1 am". Maybe am I wrong?

Comment: Answer is correct. Every 6 hour - `*/6` or means 0,6,12,18,0 or 12

Comment: Then why are `0 */ * * *` and `0 * * * *` not the same...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54555/discussion-between-lnux-and-blaszard).

Comment: @Lnux _"No, it will run at every 1 am."_ - No it won't; `*/1` is identical to `*`, so `0 */1 * * *` means every hour.

Comment: @marcelm Yes,..you're right.realized in chat discussion